# EventBridge Scheduler can't update ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I want to shutdown\startup ECS tasks by schedule for saving costs.
I decided to use EventBridge Scheduler to update service **desiredTaskCount** to 0 and back to the desired amount.

The problem is the console interface doesn't provide any clues how to pass the correct data. it just promts for a JSON object in the following format:
[image]

And this is completely different from [API description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateService.html) for UpdateSerivce operation.

So I'm not sure what's the correct way of passing service ARN and the properties I want to update.
I've tried out several formats but it doesn't work so far:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The is no any clarifications or examples in the documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing "Cluster" in the request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the service name and cluster name in update service in EventBridge.

```
{
  "Service": "service_name",
  "Cluster": "cluster_name",
  "DesiredCount": 0/1
}
```